# How to prove $f^{-1}(0)$ is a sub-manifold of $\Bbb R P^3$?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, projective-space, submanifold

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}P^3 \to \mathbb{R}$

$$f (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = \frac{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-x_4^2}{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2}$$

Is $f^{-1}(0)$ a sub-manifold of $\mathbb{R}P^3$?

My approach is to extend $f$ to $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^4$, and check that every vector in $T_{p}\mathbb{R}P^3$ is in $\ker dF_{p}$. ($p$ is a point in $f^{-1}(0)$) However, I think it is difficult to explicitly express a vetor in $T_{p}\mathbb{R}P^3$.

Comment: By submersion theorem, you just need to show that $Df$ is nonvanishing on $\mathbb{RP}^3$.

Comment: Is there any method other than my approach to show it? Because I am not sure about the tangent space of RP^3.

Comment: Do you know the description of local coordinate systems that cover $\mathbb R P^3$? If so then you can apply the submersion theorem (mentioned in the comment of @user10354138) to reduce this problem quickly to some calculations of derivatives and matrix ranks.

Comment: Do you know how to see $T_p \mathbb{RP}^3$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$?

Comment: thanks!! I did it by using local coordinate.

Comment: I'm not familiar with it. Can you give me reference?@Arctic char